# How to run a Hive command from within Oozie Java action?

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, oozie

I have an oozie workflow which runs a Java action. Within the java action, I need to describe a Hive table to get the schema of the table. I do this by using a process builder and executing a shell script containing the `describe table query`

My describeTable.sh:

```
hive -e 'describe <tableName>`
```

Once the java code generates this script, I copy it to `/tmp` on the local FS and then execute the script using process builder as follows:

```
fs.copyToLocalFile(bashScriptPath, new Path("/tmp/describeTable.sh"));
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "/tmp/describeTable.sh");
```

The script executes, but it fails to recognize `hive` as a command

```
/tmp/describeTable.sh: line 1: hive: command not found
```

I've also tried `/usr/bin/hive -e 'describe <tableName>'` , but it doesn't work as well.

The java program works fine when I execute it as a jar file  on local FS, but when I run it as part of an oozie workflow, it fails.

I'm not sure how to get this working, I would really appreciate some ideas.

**EDIT**

Adding the full code for process builder:

```
fs.copyToLocalFile(bashScriptPath, new Path("/tmp/describeTable.sh"));
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "/tmp/describeTable.sh");
    builder.directory(new File(currentLocalDir));
    ArrayList<String> columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
    System.err.println("trying to run script");
    try {
        final Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        BufferedReader error1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
        String errorLine=null;
        System.err.println("error stream: ");
        while((errorLine=error1.readLine())!=null){
            System.err.println(errorLine);
        }
        String line;
        System.err.println("input stream");
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null) {
            System.err.println("line from running script: " + line);
            String[] output = line.split("\t");
            columnList.add(output[0]);

        }
        is.close();
        isr.close();
        br.close();
        System.err.println("column list:" + columnList);
        return columnList;
```

Comment: try to run 'which hive' or 'echo $PATH' from your describeTable.sh to see why it can't find hive

Comment: It says hive command not found... I guess hive isn't installed on all nodes of the cluster?

Comment: echo $PATH prints a blank line btw..

Comment: bingo! There is something wrong with the way you use ProcessBuilder

Comment: @Oleksii, I've added the full code for the process builder part. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: what's the error when you specify full path to hive?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40763/discussion-between-chaos-and-oleksii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oozie runs most if not all actions as Map Reduce jobs, so the error message you're seeing is probably because the java action is being executed on one of your compute nodes, not the machine from where your submitted your oozie job, or the machine where the Oozie server is running.

You can either ensure that hive is installed on all compute nodes in your cluster, or use the Hive Java API in your Java Action and add the hive libraries (and all dependencies) to your Oozie job's shared library path in HDFS.